# What does this graph represent?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

I dont understand the second graph below. If I understand the first one right, it represents the potential energy between two atoms. So if we bring them closer together or separate them past the equilibrium  we need to add energy.

[image]

But what does this graph below describe and what are those "zoomed in" lines of the graph?

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the quantization of energy states in a potential well?

Comment: @DanDan0101, I know that electrons behave like standing waves in an atom and that they are on certain energy level in the atom which depend on n for hydrogen. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You should give a link for the graphs. This way they are out of contex and cannot be answered

Answer (score 3):

From memory this applies to atoms in chemical bonds.

In the first graph it shows the potential for the primary energy level (the black line), the red line shows  what's called the harmonic oscillator potential (more on later).
The second set of graphs show an additional set of energy levels that exist for each of the different primary energy levels, they come from considering both the oscillation of the bond, and rotation of the molecule, both of them are quantised, with quantum numbers $\nu$ for the oscillator and $l$ for the rotation energy levels.

It turns out that the oscillator energy is far greater than the rotational energy and uses the classical [harmonic oscillator potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator).

So what the second graph shows is that the total energy is first from the primary energy level then there is a little bit extra from the oscillator energy then there is an even smaller contribution from rotational motion.

Hopefully that helps.